# Catel and TreeView example

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I found an example of using Catel together with TreeView [here](https://catel.codeplex.com/discussions/399785), but unfortunately this example is built on Catel version 3.3 I tried to repeat it on Catel version 4.0 but unfortunately it did not work.

When I try in my project (which based on Catel version 4.0) to bind to properties in the class TreeViewItemToDataContext a reference to the ViewModel in the UserControl is missing. 
[image]

but the example is based on version 3.3, everything works fine. I wanted to get the link manually using IViewModelManager but unfortunately in version 4 viewModel is not generated in version 3.3 all works fine.

[image: ver 4]

[image: ver 3]
Question how can I to run the example on Catel version 4.0? 
P.S. [My test App](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ik5z2hhg6lgr0cu/WpfApplication4.rar?dl=0)

**Update**

```
public class TreeViewItemToDataContext : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var uc = value as Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl;

        if (uc != null)
        {
            uc.ViewModelChanged += this.OnViewModelChanged;
            return uc.DataContext;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void OnViewModelChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var uc = sender as Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl;
        if (uc != null)
        {
            var visualParent = uc.TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter;
            if (visualParent != null)
            {
                var treeViewItem = visualParent.TemplatedParent as TreeViewItem;
                if (treeViewItem != null)
                {
                    var IsSelectedBinding = new Binding("IsSelected");
                    IsSelectedBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                    IsSelectedBinding.Source = uc.ViewModel;
                    treeViewItem.SetBinding(TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, IsSelectedBinding);

                    var IsExpandedBinding = new Binding("IsExpanded");
                    IsExpandedBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                    IsExpandedBinding.Source = uc.ViewModel;
                    treeViewItem.SetBinding(TreeViewItem.IsExpandedProperty, IsExpandedBinding);

                    uc.ViewModelChanged -= this.OnViewModelChanged;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ExpandCommand

```
 private void OnSetFocusAndExpandCommandExecute()
    {
        var model = this.ProviderGroups[0]; // open First Level
        var viewModelManager = this.GetServiceLocator().ResolveType<IViewModelManager>();
        var viewModels = viewModelManager.GetViewModelsOfModel(model);
        if (viewModels.Length > 0)
        {
            // NOTE: Somehow there are two viewmodels per model 
            var viewModel = viewModels[0] as TreeViewItemViewModel;
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                //viewModel.IsSelected = true;
                viewModel.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }

        var model1 = this.ProviderGroups[0].Categories.First();  // open Second Level
        var viewModels1 = viewModelManager.GetViewModelsOfModel(model1); // ViewModel Not created. 
        if (viewModels1.Length > 0)
        {
            // NOTE: Somehow there are two viewmodels per model 
            var viewModel1 = viewModels1[0] as TreeViewItemViewModel;
            if (viewModel1 != null)
            {
                viewModel1.IsSelected = true;
                viewModel1.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The view models in Catel are now loaded when they are really only needed (lazy loading) instead of eager loading. If you override the *OnViewModelChanged* on the user control, you will see it is being set later.

You can subscribe to the ViewModelChanged event in your converted and await the first event (don't forget to unsubscribe then).

Comment: Thank you Geert. I changed TreeViewItemToDataContext and now I can expand first level, but what if I want to open second level. If I write this code (see Update  my first post ) ViewModel for second level even will not be created. P.S.   
Maybe you know a more elegant way to work with the Treeview?